# MongoDB autowire is throwing exception

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have below class files and it looks everything fine but i am not understanding why i am getting autowire failure. Can anyone please help me to find the issue?

updated with package details

```
 package com.ui.controller;

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Person")
    public class PersonController {

        @Autowired
        @Lazy
        private RepoService repoService;

    }

    package com.messaging.service.impl;
    @Component
    @Lazy
    public class RepoServiceImpl implements RepoService {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("personRepository")
        private PersonRepository personRepo;

    }

    package com.messaging.service;
    public interface RepoService {

    }


    package com.da.repository;
    @Repository("personRepository")
    public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<SomeType, String> {
    }


    package com.conf;
    @Configuration
    @EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.da.repository")
    @EnableMongoAuditing
    @Profile("mongo")
    public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    }
```

I am getting following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.da.repository.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=personRepository)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
... 52 more
```

Comment: In which pacjage your classes are located?

Comment: @jens - updated with package details

Comment: And all beans are instanciated by spring?

Comment: @jens - yes all are intiatiated by spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its my bad. The issue was not with the above coding but with the mongodb connection. There was a connection issue which resulted the above error.